# python http request to elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have method make http request. I use this to update docs in es with update_ by_query api of elasticsearch. 
Here is the code:
import httplib

```
def http(method, path, data,HOST):
    conn = httplib.HTTPConnection(HOST)
    conn.request(method, path, data)
    return conn.getresponse()

updateDsl ="""{
                      \"query\": {
                        \"filtered\": {
                          \"filter\": {
                            \"bool\": {
                              \"must\": [
                                {
                                  \"term\": {
                                    \"heroname\": \"king\"
                                  }
                                },
                                {
                                  \"missing\": {
                                    \"field\": \"category\"
                                  }
                                }
                              ]
                            }
                          }
                        }
                      },
                      \"script\" : \"ctx._source.category = \\"27"\\"\"
                    }"""
try:
    result = http("POST","dota2/_update_by_query",updateDsl,"localhost:9200")
except Exception as ex:
    ex.message()
```

I expect this works because I run same dsl query in marvel and check docs see it works fine.. also debug python ,and check response code is 'OK'
But docs not change..

here is the dsl result after run update_by_query command(under _search) in marvel:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I post it in a loop and check the response from elastisearch, here how it works:

```
for name in clientInfo:
            myDoc = """{  \"query\": {    \"filtered\": {      \"filter\": {        \"and\": [            {              \"term\": {                \"clientip\": \"%s\"              }            }, {              \"missing\": {                \"field\": \"clientname\"              }            }          ]      }    }  },  \"script\" : \"ctx._source.clientname = \\"%s\\"\"}"""%(name,clientInfo[name])
            result = self.http("POST","/"+self.elastic_index+"/_update_by_query",myDoc,self.elastic_con_string)

status = json.loads(result.read())

if not status['ok'] == True:
    raise ValueError("There is an error ocurred during update document")
```